# php array values conditional printing

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

this is my $array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#374 (49) {
    ["value1_name"]=>
    string(x) "value1"
    ["value2_name"]=>
    string(y) "value2"
  }

  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#375 (49) {
    ["value1_name"]=>
    string(x) "value3"
    ["value2_name"]=>
    string(y) "value4"
  }
```

I want to print the **value1_name** value **if value2_name value is equal to value2**.
So I expect to print the **value1**.
How can I achieve this?
I hope I've been clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `foreach loop` like

```
foreach ($myarray as $val)
{
   if ( $val->value2_name == "value2")
       echo $val->value1_name;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`. Do you mean like following?

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
   if($value->value2_name == "value2")
      echo $value->value1_name;
   else
      // something to do
}
```